# TCPDF UTF-8. INR symbols not showing

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

```
        tcpdf();
        $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
        $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
        $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
        $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
        $obj_pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);
        $obj_pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);
        //$obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 0);
        $obj_pdf->SetMargins(5, 5, 5,true);
        $obj_pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
        $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
        $obj_pdf->AddPage();
        ob_start();
```

I am using below configuration but not able to generate INR symbol. It show "?" instead of INR symbol.

How can generate INR symbol?

Comment: You can use HTML entities &#8377; also check this link: https://tcpdf.org/docs/source_docs/classTCPDF/#ae4bdb1a4c29d0a0d707caad308dcd320

Comment: I tried with HTML entities **&#8377;** but it wont work. It shows "?" symbol.

Comment: try Encodes from this link: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm

Answer (score 4):

To view the symbol in TCPDF generated PDF's, it is necessary to use a font that supports the Indian Rupee Symbol. You may find such a font from the list at the page https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/fontsupport.htm.

Example:

DejaVu Sans supports displaying Indian Rupee fonts. Locate such a font from TCPDF fonts directory. If the name of the font is `dejavusans`, use it in the html to generate generate PDF.

```html
<span style="font-family:dejavusans;">&#8377;</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this issue with image instead of symbol.

```
$rupee_sym = '<img style="width:8px;" src="assets/images/rupee-indian.png" />';
```

And print it where you want:

```
echo $rupee_sym;
```

Hope this is helpful. :)